# Not getting Linear Regression Plot

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to plot linear regression between two parameters from my data set. But I am not able to do so, I am getting an error

> Error in plot.default(yh, r, xlab = l.fit, ylab = "Residuals", main =
>   main,  :    formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual
>   arguments

Here is my code

```
file <- "bank.csv"
data <- read.csv(file, header=TRUE, sep=";")
data <- data[(data$Previous_Outcome == "success") | (data$Previous_Outcome == "nonexistent"),]
data <- data[(data$Duration != "0"),]
age = data$Age
duration <- data$Duration
fit <- lm(age ~ duration)
png(filename = "AgevsDurationRegression.png", width=480, height=480, units="px")
> plot(fit, main="Age vs Call Duration Regression", xlab = "Duration in Seconds", ylab = "Age in Years")
Error in plot.default(yh, r, xlab = l.fit, ylab = "Residuals", main = main,  : 
  formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

str(data) and summary(fit) gave me this

```
summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = age ~ duration)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-23.063  -8.045  -2.027   6.956  58.007 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 40.0792439  0.0752589 532.551   <2e-16 ***
duration    -0.0001804  0.0002040  -0.884    0.377    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 10.28 on 36930 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  2.117e-05, Adjusted R-squared:  -5.903e-06 
F-statistic: 0.782 on 1 and 36930 DF,  p-value: 0.3765
```

Comment: have you tried only plot(fit)? It will plot for 4 graphics not only one.

Comment: I tried that. It just opened a blank window and nothing happened. I also want to save the result as an image. I am failing in both.

Comment: I gave. I just did not post the result for str(data) because it was too long. But the result for str(data) seems fine to me. I will post it if you still want to see.

Comment: o.k.. But you are using `plot.lm()`. this function has no parameter `xlab=`. Use `plot(age ~ duration)` (or `plot(duration, age)`) and after fitting `abline(fit)`.

Comment: Basically when I use plot(duration, age, ....) and execute, I am getting the result but without the regression line. But only when I am trying to get the line also in the plot, I am not getting result. Any help?

Comment: Try `fit <- lm(Age ~ Duration, data=data); plot(Age ~ Duration, data=data); abline(fit)` And: first try without `png(...)` !

Comment: Till plot(..) I got the scatter plot but without the regression line. When I executed abline, I got this "Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
"

Comment: just add a reproductible example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked

```
file <- "bank.csv"
data <- read.csv(file, header=TRUE, sep=";")
data <- data[(data$Previous_Outcome == "success") | (data$Previous_Outcome == "nonexistent"),]
data <- data[(data$Duration != "0"),]
age = data$Age
duration <- data$Duration
png("file1.png")
plot(duration~age)
abline(lm(duration~age))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Difference between plot(y~x) and plot(lm(y~x)):**

plot(y~x) gives a scatter plot of variables y Vs x. and abline(lm(y~x)) adds a regression line to the plot.

plot(lm(y~x)) provides regression diagnostic plots for regression model. 
It produces six diagnostic plots for given regression model.

- Residuals against fitted values
- Sqrt (residuals)  against fitted values
- Normal Q-Q plot
- Cook's distances versus row labels
- Residuals against leverages
- Cook's distances against leverage/(1-leverage).

**By default, the first three and 5 are provided.**

Hit enter to see these plots one by one. 
Or to see all four plots in one window, use the following command. It divides plot area into 2*2 grid.

```
  par(mfrow=c(2,2))
```

To save any plot in png format:

```
  png(file="myplot", width=400, height=350)
  dev.off()
```

Similary, you can use

```
  bmp(file="myplot", width=400, height=350); 
  jpeg(file="myplot", width=400, height=350) or
  tiff(file="myplot", width=400, height=350)
```

functions to save any plot in other formats.